# Coverflow in blackberry10

Tags: qml, coverflow, blackberry-10

I am developing an application in blackbery10 with native SDK. And I want to show cover-flow in my application.But I didn't found component for doing cover-flow. How can I do Cover-flow in Blackberry10 through QML.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should use PathView element to implement cover flow like effects. Documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-pathview.html) and some examples [here](https://idlebox.net/2010/apidocs/qt-everywhere-opensource-4.7.0.zip/declarative-modelviews-pathview.html) and [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/PathView_QML_Element)

Comment: I tried your suggestion,but Path View is not supported in the QML

Comment: It is one of the default QML language elements at least in Qt 4.7 onwards. Maybe you are using a wrong import: import QtQuick 1.1. You should be able to use it if you import QtQuick 1.1 in your QML file.

Comment: No QtQuick1.1 is not shown in the IDE. IDE is not suggesting me QtQuick

Comment: Sorry I thought that you were using Qt for your development. It however seems that Cascades for BlackBerry also have a wrapper for PathView see [this](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qml-pathview.html)

Answer (score 0):

not really apple-like cover flow, but you can create image carousel like this sample: https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Community-Samples/tree/master/stumpers/bbjamcarousel

Comment: i have imported this in my IDE but when I try to compile it shows error like this "src/Carousel.cpp:24:24: fatal error: bb/ImageData: No such file or directory" what is the problem here